# Preventing Xamarin(/Mono?) from optimizing on iOS

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin

When I use reflection in ViewDidLoad like this:

```
foreach (var m in this.GetType().GetMethods()) {
            Console.WriteLine (m.Name); 
}
```

without any other code,  methods like

```
Add
set_View
```

are not there; when I add;

```
public void PreventOptimizing() {
    var x = this.View; 
    this.View = x; 
    this.Add (null); 
}
```

to the class and without calling that method, they are there. So I assume the AOT compilation optimizes these methods away as they are not called. I don't know which methods it adds away so I would like the compiler, for my experiment, not to optimize anything away. How can that be done? Or is there another trick preventing automated removal of method?

Edit: so full code, if this isn't clear enough;

1. result output will not contain 'Add' and 'set_View';

> ```
> public class TestController : UIViewController
> {
>
>     public override void ViewDidLoad ()
>   {
>          base.ViewDidLoad ();
>
>       foreach (var m in this.GetType().GetMethods()) {
>           Console.WriteLine (m.Name); 
>       }
>     }
> }
> ```

1. Output does contain Add and set_View;

> ```
> public class TestController : UIViewController
> {
>   public void PreventOptimizing() {
>       var x = this.View; 
>       this.View = x; 
>       this.Add (null); 
>   }
>   public override void ViewDidLoad ()
>   {
>          base.ViewDidLoad ();
>
>       foreach (var m in this.GetType().GetMethods()) {
>           Console.WriteLine (m.Name); 
>       }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You either set the linker option to "Link SDK assemblies only" or use the [PreserveAttribute](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.Foundation.PreserveAttribute) on the class.

Details are in Xamarin website:
http://developer.xamarin.com/Guides/ios/Advanced_Topics/Linker/

> **Linker Behavior**
>
> The linking process can be customized in different ways. The primary
>   mechanism for controlling the linker in Xamarin Studio is the Linker
>   Behavior drop-down in the iOS Build Xamarin Studio's Project Options
>   dialog box. In Visual Studio, this is located in project Properties,
>   under iOS Build.
>
> **Preserving Code**
>
> When you use the linker it can sometimes remove code
>   that you might have called dynamically either using
>   System.Reflection.MemberInfo.Invoke, or by exporting your methods to
>   Objective-C using the [Export] attribute and then invoking the
>   selector manually.
>
> **In those cases, you can instruct the linker to consider either entire
>   classes to be used or individual members to be preserved by applying
>   the [Xamarin.iOS.Foundation.Preserve] attribute either at the
>   class-level or the member-level.** Every member that is not statically
>   linked by the application is subject to be removed. This attribute is
>   hence used to mark members that are not statically referenced, but
>   that are still needed by your application.
>
> For instance, if you instantiate types dynamically, you may want to
>   preserve the default constructor of your types. If you use XML
>   serialization, you may want to preserve the properties of your types.
>
> You can apply this attribute on every member of a type, or on the type
>   itself. If you want to preserve the whole type, you can use the syntax
>   **[Preserve (AllMembers = true)]** on the type.
>
> Sometimes you want to preserve certain members, but only if the
>   containing type was preserved. In those cases, use [Preserve
>   (Conditional=true)]

Comment: Thanks. But incidentally I have "Link SDK Assemblies only" set always because of a (new, yesterday's update) bug in Xamarin Studio and that makes no difference; it still removes the code. And I cannot put Preserve everywhere as I cannot be sure what will be used...

Comment: Ok, so Xamarin says to actually Don't Link to preserve everything. So this behaviour was actually all a nice coincidence of that bug and me trying this reflection after I circumvented that... 

(and the update was from 3 july, but I only updated yesterday and had this new bug)